# react-router is not letting Link send a GET request to the server

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Normally I would send a GET request using axios, but in the 'React Practice Course' tutorial, the instructor successfully hits this route

```
app.get('/api/admin/download/:filename', auth, admin, (req, res) => {
    console.log('here I am ', req.params.filename);
    const file = path.resolve('.')+`/uploads/${req.params.filename}`;
    res.download(file);
})
```

with the Links in this code

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

showFiles = () => (
    this.state.files &&
    this.state.files.map((filename,i) => (
        <li key={i}>
            <Link   to={`/api/admin/download/${filename}`}
                    target="_blank">
                {filename}
            </Link>
        </li>
    ))
)
```

As seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qr19cal6iafddy/i6jyq7s4.jpg?raw=1), the link matches the path in the server, but react router is sending me to the PageNotFound component instead, and never sends the GET request.

What am I missing to make a Link file reach the server? I suspect the problem is in my routes file.

```
const Routes = () => {
    // null = public route
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/admin/add_product" exact component={Auth(AddProduct, true)} />
                <Route path="/admin/manage_categories" exact component={Auth(ManageCategories, true)} />
                <Route path="/admin/manage_site" exact component={Auth(ManageSite, true)} />
                <Route path="/admin/add_file" exact component={Auth(AddFile, true)} />

                <Route path="/user/cart" exact component={Auth(Cart, true)} />
                <Route path="/user/dashboard" exact component={Auth(Dashboard, true)} />
                <Route path="/user/user_profile" exact component={Auth(UpdateProfile, true)} />

                <Route path="/register_login" exact component={Auth(RegisterLogin, false)} />
                <Route path="/register" exact component={Auth(Register, false)} />
                <Route path="/product/:id" exact component={Auth(Product, null)} />
                <Route path="/shop" exact component={Auth(Shop, null)} />
                <Route path="/" exact component={Auth(Home, null)} />
                <Route component={Auth(PageNotFound)} />
            </Switch>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<Route path="/api/admin/download/:filename" .....` ? Right now you dont have any route matching that url in your Router

Comment: wouldn't that route mean I wanted to take care of the route on the front end, instead of passing the request on to the server?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147#issuecomment-113180174

Comment: I missunderstood you. Basically if you dont want the Router to control your link you either create your own wrapper around Link or just use a regular anchor

Comment: Thanks. Should have mentioned that I already tried <a> tags and got the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To expand my comments I answer here.

The following works for me:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const About = () => <div>About</div>
const Home = () => <div>Home</div>
const Topics = () => <div>Topics</div>

const apiUrl = "http://localhost:9000/api";

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href={`${apiUrl}/v1/test`}>Api GET request</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<BasicExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

So basically I just created an `<a>` passing the proper `href` url and it didn't fall into `<Router>`, as indicated here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147#issuecomment-113180174

Are you sure you are passing the right url to the anchor's href?

Comment: Thanks. I can see how that works. Changing up my entire router now to see why the tutorial skipped using BrowserRouter...

Comment: BrowserRouter is indeed in there, (was unable to edit the last comment), and I'm pretty sure my url is correct. Was trying to prove it was correct via the screenshot I linked in the original question.